# iOS log shows NSArray object is __NSDictionaryM

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use an NSArray to store data, but when I log it's class (because it was giving me errors) it returns `__NSDictionaryM`. The only time I add any info to it is when I do this

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:aa, nil];
```

The object `aa` is a string. What would turn the array into a dictionary?

Ok, I pass this array to a different class using a delegate:

```
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in [[p objectAtIndex:0] elementsForName:@"TrackDetail"]) {
NSString *aa = resultElement.stringValue;
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:aa, nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
[self.delegate XMLAvailable:a done:(a.count > 0)];
   });
```

I then do this in the other class

```
- (void)XMLAvailable:(NSArray *)array done:(BOOL)done{
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
for(int i = [self.imageInfos count]; i < [self.imageInfos count] + [array count]; ++i) {
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
NSLog(@"%@", array.class);
self.imageInfos = array;
NSLog(@"%@", self.imageInfos.class);
[self.tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
```

but for some reason, in the method above, `array.class` logs `__NSDictionaryM`

Comment: Every objects in `ObjectiveC` is `dynamically typed`. may be you are assigning dictionary object to array somewhere not here

Comment: @ACB yes I am using ARC

Comment: Are you assigning something dynamically on a. Such as `a = someObject; `

Comment: the only other object I'm assigning is `NSString *aa = resultElement.stringValue;`

Comment: When are you seeing this change? Is it in same method? Is it possible to post some more code.

Comment: @ACB I added more code

Comment: This should work fine. I cant see anything wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I just needed to reset things on my app, because after restoring my phone (it froze up and wouldn't restart) everything is working again and they are being logged as NSArrays

Answer (score 0):

Try running with zombies enabled. If your array is accidentally being deallocated and a dictionary is allocated at the same address, you would get symptoms like this.